# Function mapping

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

If there is a set $|A| = n$ and set $|B| = m$ how many functions are mapping $A$ to $B$?

It has been established that this is $m^n$.

How many of these are one-to-one?
I think this means that each element of $|A|$ is fixed to a unique $|B|$.

Comment: Remark: the set of such functions is often denoted by $B^A$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider an arbitrary function $f$, from $A$ to $B$, each element in $A$ has $m$ choices for where $f$ could take it in $B$. There are $n$ elements in $A$, hence $n$ choices to be made. Therefore, there are $m^n$ such functions.

If you want your function to be one-to-one, then put some ordering on $A$ and call its elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. $a_1$ could go to any of the $m$ elements of $B$, but then $a_2$ can only go to $m - 1$ of the elements (if it went to the same place as $a_1$, the function wouldn't be one-to-one). Similarly, $a_3$ can only go to $m - 2$ of the elements, ..., $a_n$ can only go to $m - (n - 1)$ of the elements. Therefore, there are $m \cdot (m - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (m - (n - 1)) = \frac{m!}{(m - n)!}$ possible one-to-one functions. Note you must have $m \geq n$ for there to be any one-to-one functions.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \frac{m!}{m-n!}$?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon yes thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$m^n$ is right 
if we let element in A be $a1,a2...an$
in B be $b1,b2...bm$

then every $ai$ has $m$ kinds of choice to be destination.

so in sum $m^n$

if one to one 
there must be $m>n$
then for $a1$ he has m kinds of choice and $ai$ has m-i+1
so in sum $m(m-1)...(m-i+1)...(m-n+1)=m!/(m-n)!$

Comment: The answer is $m^n$, not $n^m$.  And please enclose your math with dollar signs.

Comment: Thankyou for you advice I am new here

Answer (score 0):

Think what it means for a function to map from A into B. It is pairing an element of A with one and only one element of B. How many ways can we do that? Think similarly for one-to-one functions. (The number of surjective functions are a lot trickier to count.)